# Overflow bug in EVM?

Tags: solidity, overflow

I think I found a EVM bug regarding integer overflow:

The below works:

```
uint16 a = 1;
uint256 b = a * 0.001 ether;
```

But, the below fails due to the overflow:

```
uint16 a = 1000;
uint256 b = a * 0.001 ether;
```

To my understandings, for the multiplication of uints with different precisions, it should cast the smaller one (uint16 in the above example) to the bigger one (uint256)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a bug, that's the expected behavior, let me explain why.

First It doesn't cast in the order you mentioned, from the [docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/types.html#operators):

> - If the type of the right operand can be implicitly converted to the type of the left operand, use the type of the left operand,
> - if the type of the left operand can be implicitly converted to the type of the right operand, use the type of the right operand,
> - otherwise, the operation is not allowed.

If we apply this to your code,
a is a type of uint16 with max value `65535`, `0.001 ether` has no explicit type, the compiler will implicitly give it the smallest datatype it accepts i.e uint56 with a max value of `72057594037927935`.

Now we have uint16 and uint56 and the value of multiplying `1000` with `0.001 ether` is `1000000000000000000` which is a type of uint64.

Let's back to the docs and see where our case fits,

- (try the left operand type on the right operand ) fails because the result is higher than uint16
- (try the right operand type on the left operand ) fails because the result is higher than uint56

The operation is not allowed so it reverts.